# VSCode Git does not correctly display the commit in the file

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm doing the following `git flow` process:

1. Standardized branchs (`feat`, `hotfix` etc)
2. `Commit` and push on these branchs
3. `Opening` of `PR`
4. `Merging` of `PR` in the `main` using "GIT crush and unite".

In `Git` my last commit in this file which I will display, this is the one in the image below **(which is correct)**:

[image]

However in `vscode`, even with the updated `branch`, it is showing that my last `commit` in the file was this:
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does the revision for #31 show the file if you run `git show --name-status the-id-of-revision-for-#31`?

Comment: Is "crush and unite" (step 4) a back-translation-into-English from some forward translation of "squash" into some other language? Git does have a `git merge --squash` option, but not a `git merge --crush-and-unite` option... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The information you show in your screen capture depends on the highlighted *line*, it may change if you move the cursor around.

VS Code displays the same information as `git blame file`, which computes, line by line, what commit last modified that specific line.